# Вопрос по AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть скрипт, перехода между страницами, путём подгрузки:

```
var main = {
loading: function() {
    var app = angular.module('mainJContent', []);
    app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl:'/lib/php/index',
            title: 'Hello World'
        }).
        when('/profile/', {
            templateUrl:'/lib/php/profile',
            title: 'Profile'
        }).
        when('/action/', {
            templateUrl:'/lib/php/action?_='+Math.random(),
            title: 'Action'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo:'/'
        });
        });
    app.run(['$location', '$rootScope', function($location, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
            if (current.$route) {
                $rootScope.title = current.$route.title;
            }
        });
    }]);
}
};
```

Так вот, как сделать к примеру, чтобы был запрос к примеру [Profile](/profile/123), GET запросом:

```
            when('/profile/123 (Типо id)', {
            templateUrl:'/lib/php/profile?i=123',
            title: 'Profile'
        }).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ангуляр не для того создавался, чтобы сервер генерировал страницу по заданному id.

Но вообще, там можно вместо константы передать функцию, которая должна возвращать путь к шаблону или сам шаблон. Если уж очень надо, то можно пойти таки путём.